# Ray tracing: making a plane for sphere

Tags: c++, raytracing, plane

I am working on an assignment where I need to ray trace a sphere with a plane (floor). I have the sphere but I am having trouble with the plane. I use the ray-plane intersection formula:
t = -(o-p).n / d.n. I have this in Plane.h, however when I run my code I get errors from Ray.h. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Plane.h

```
`#include "..\..\raytrace\Ray.h"

class Plane
{
    using Colour = cv::Vec3b; // RGB Value 

private:
    Vec3 normal_;
    Vec3 distance_;
    Colour color_;

public:
    Plane();

    Plane(Vec3 norm, Vec3 dis, Colour color) : normal_(norm), distance_(dis), color_(color) {}

    Vec3 norm() const {
        return normal_;
    }


    Vec3 dis() const {
        return distance_;
    }


    Colour color() const {
        return color_;
    }

    float findIntersection(Ray ray) {

        Vec3 rayDirection = ray.mPosition();

        float denominator = rayDirection.dot(normal_);

        if (denominator == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        else {
            //mPosition() is origin in Ray.h
            float t = -(((ray.mPosition() - distance_)).dot(normal_)) / denominator;
        }
    }
};
```

`
Ray.h

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <cmath>
#include "Image.h"


// Data types
typedef float Scalar; //**custom datatype: Scalar is float
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 3, 1> Vec3; //***Vec3 is a custom datatype (specific kind)
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 2, 1> Vec2;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

class Ray
{
private:
    Vec3 mPosition_; //point

public:
    Ray() {}
    //constuctor, when we construct ray we get mPosition_
    Ray(Vec3 mPosition) :  mPosition_(mPosition) {
        //
    }

    float t;  

    Vec3 mPosition() const {
        return mPosition_;
    }

public:
    inline Vec3 generateRay(Vec3 const& pt) {

        Vec3 origin = mPosition_;
        Vec3 direction = pt - mPosition_; // d = s -e, pt is pixel Position
        direction.normalize(); 
        return pt + t * direction;
    }

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include "Image.h"

#include "Ray.h"
#include "../build/raytrace/Plane.h"

//Color functions
using Colour = cv::Vec3b; // RGB Value 
//Color is a Vec3b datatype, use Color instead of Vec3b, it has 3 vectors, hold 3 values b/w 0-255
Colour red() { return Colour(255, 0, 0); }
Colour green() { return Colour(0, 255,0); }
Colour blue() { return Colour(0, 0, 255); }
Colour white() { return Colour(255, 255, 255); }
Colour black() { return Colour(0, 0, 0); }


//bounding the channel wise pixel color between 0 to 255 
//bounding the color value, if a value is beyond 255 clamp it to 255, and any value below 0 clamp to 0.
uchar Clamp(int color)
{
    if (color < 0) return 0;
    if (color >= 255) return 255;
    return color;
}

int main(int, char**){

    //Create an image object with 500 x 500 resolution.
    Image image = Image(500, 500);
    
    //Coordinates of image rectangle
    Vec3 llc = Vec3(-1, -1, -1); //**llc - lower left corner
    Vec3 urc = Vec3(1, 1, -1); //**urc - upper right corner
    int width = urc(0) - llc(0);
    int height = urc(1) - llc(1);
    Vec2 pixelUV = Vec2((float)width / image.cols, (float)height / image.rows);
    
    /// TODO: define camera position (view point), sphere center, sphere radius (Weightage: 5%)
    Vec3 CameraPoint = Vec3(0, 0, 0); //**it is the origin
    Vec3 SphereCenter = Vec3(0, 0, -5); //**it is the Sphere Position

    float SphereRadius = 2.0;
 
        Vec3 LightSource = Vec3(2.0, 0.0, 3.0); //**
    Vec3 ambient = Vec3(0, 0, 0.5); //**
    Vec3 diffuse = Vec3(224, 180, 255); //** 0, 255, 100 - green 

    Vec3 Origin = CameraPoint;
    //end


    for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
            //TODO: Build primary rays  
            //Find the pixel position (PixelPos) for each row and col and then construct the vector PixelPos-Origin
           
            Vec3 pixelPos = Vec3(llc(0) + pixelUV(0) * (col + 0.5), llc(1) + pixelUV(1) * (row + 0.5), -1); 
              
            //create a ray object
            Ray r; //**

            //Vec3 rayDir = pixelPos - Origin; //**direction of the ray

            Vec3 rayDir = r.generateRay(pixelPos); //**pixelPos-Origin
            rayDir.normalize(); //**normalize the ray direction vector
            
            //Ray-sphere intersection...(refer to the lecture slides and Section 4.4.1 of the textbook) 

            float a = rayDir.dot(rayDir);
            Vec3 s0_r0 = Origin - SphereCenter; //***s0_r0 - sphere center  - ray origin
            float b = 2.0 * rayDir.dot(s0_r0);
            float c = s0_r0.dot(s0_r0) - pow(SphereRadius, 2);
            //compute the discriminant
             
            float discriminant = pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c; 
            
            
            //if the discriminant is greater than zero
            if(discriminant > 0){
            
            
                //find roots t1 and t2
                float t1 = (-b - sqrt((pow(b, 2)) - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a); //**
                float t2 = (-b + sqrt((pow(b, 2)) - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a); //**
                //determine which one is the real intersection point
                float t; 
            //Sphere s;
                if (t1 < t2 && (t1 > 0 && t2 > 0)) {
                    t = t1;
                    //} //should this be after the if-statement below, so that it uses t = t1 and not just float t.????
                    if (t > 0) {
                        //Shade the pixel, normal is Intersection - SphereCenter, LightVector is LightSource- Intersection, make sure to normalize the vectors

                        Vec3 Intersection = Origin + (t * rayDir);
                        Vec3 Normal = Intersection - SphereCenter; //** normalize
                        Normal.normalize(); //**
                        Vec3 LightVector = LightSource - Intersection; //**normalize
                        LightVector.normalize(); //**

                        float diffuseTerm = LightVector.dot(Normal);
                        if (diffuseTerm < 0) diffuseTerm = 0;

                        Colour colour(0, 0, 0); //The ambient base
                        colour[0] = Clamp(ambient[0] + diffuse[0] * diffuseTerm);
                        colour[1] = Clamp(ambient[1] + diffuse[1] * diffuseTerm);
                        colour[2] = Clamp(ambient[2] + diffuse[2] * diffuseTerm);
                        image(row, col) = colour;
                    }
                }//
             
                else {
                    image(row, col) = black();
                }
            
            } else {
                //No intersection, discriminant < 0
                image(row, col) = red(); //**makes blue background colour 
            }

            ////**Plane intersection
            //create a plane object
           Plane plane(Vec3(-5, 0, -4), Vec3(0, 0, -1), black()); 
           //Plane plane;
           ////if ray hits plane -> color black
           //if (plane.findIntersection(rayDir) == 1) {
           //    image(row, col) = black();

           //}
           //else {
           //    image(row, col) = white();

           //}


       }
    }
    /// Required outputs: (1) Ray traced image of a sphere (2) Ray traced image when the camera is placed inside the sphere (complete black)
    image.save("./result.png");
    image.display();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeczm.png)

Answer (score 2):

`#include` is a shockingly simple directive. It literally just copy-pastes the content of the file.

main.cpp includes both Ray.h and Plane.h, and Plane.h includes Ray.h, so Ray.h ends up being included twice. That's why the compiler is complaining about a "class redefinition".

You can add `#pragma once` at the top of all your header files to let the compiler know know to skip the file if it was included already.

*N.B.* `#pragma once` is not officially part of the language, but it is supported by all compilers and has a few small advantages over the alternative.

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the errors. Do you know what I could do to make a plane?

Comment: @Lid That would be doing your assignment for you. You can start by googling "Ray Plane Interesection". If you encounter any other *specific* difficulty, feel free to post another question about it. One question per post.